# A planet with human-looking people who are not from Earth

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, space

This is a long shot... I remember very little of this novel I read at least 30 years ago. I was in a paperback which IIRC was already old. I read it in French but it might have been a translation.

The main point I remember is that there was something extremely improbable. The story starts on planet where the people are not descendants of Earthlings, since the whole point of the story is that Earth does not yet really know about them. But they are so similar to humans that they plan to send a (female) spy to Earth hoping she would just mingle in undetected.

A bit more details. The other planet is a unique polity ruled by a woman. IIRC, she is called "Queen" but maybe elected rather than hereditary. Anyway the present Queen is a very considerate person, both for her people in general and for each individual. And because of this, she is torn.

Indeed, for at least the second time, spaceships from far away have been detected near her planet. Since the Queens's planet also have interplanetary travel, they know where the ships come from, namely, from Earth. They also time travel, IIRC, but I am not quite sure. The Queen has already sent a spy to Earth on the first arrival of spaceships in her neighbourhood,, and she was hoping that they wouldn't come back. But now she understands that they will come again and again. So to deter Earthlings to come back she needs more information. And thus she has to send another spy, for the sake of her planet. But her sole choice is a very "green" spy, just out of her studies. And she fears for the young lady.

Curiously, I remember the beginning rather well, but I don't remember what follows.

Maybe I decided, at that time, that it was not such a good book after all, and stopped reading. But I'd like to try again...

---

EDIT

I just remembered something else. Not only are the people of the planet of the Queen able to mingle undetected with Earthlings, but they have the same aesthetical criteria. About the young lady they were sending as a spy, the Queen mentioned she was a good choice because she was "jolie" = pretty (IIRC ; but maybe the word was "belle"= beautiful). Anyway, the attractiveness criteria were probably described by the first spy they sent earlier, not just assumed to be  the same.
But why would they be the same on two different planets where two species had developed independently ?
Not very probable !

Comment: Very human-like aliens are common in science fiction. Just consider *Star Trek* and *Star Wars* and a host of planetary romance stories, including *Flash Gordon* and Burroughs' Mars and Venus books.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen  I read this a very long time ago, I had not read much SF then. I remember that, when I read it, these so "human-like" aliens clearly not descendants of Earthlings made me find the book a bit illogical. The feeling has stayed with me ever since...